# project flutter does not start on vscode but start on android studio

Tags: flutter, debugging, android-emulator

So I'm currently working on a flutter app in vs code. it does not show any error in the code .and the vs code detects the emulator .but when I start debugging it does not display anything on the emulator .but when I use android studio it starts normally.

Comment: Could be something to do with your compile/target versions in the app level build gradle. I've just experienced a similar issue with a real device, and lowering both target and compile from 33 to 32 allowed me to build with vs code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed [set up an editor](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/editor) steps?
If it doesn't work try to run the app by vs code terminal by typing `flutter run` ([Flutter CLI](https://docs.flutter.dev/reference/flutter-cli)) or `flutter run --verbose` for verbose mode.
If this also doesn't work please provide `flutter doctor -v` results.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was in the emulator system because when I create a new emulator with Android 11 it works fine for me.